# tailwind css is not working after deploy in git pages. but it work when i run it in local host

Tags: html, git, deployment, tailwind-css

tailwind css is not working after deploy in git pages. but it work when i run it in local host. i dont understand why this is happening. can u guys help me to deploy it correctly.

live page - https://rayzorpay-clone.onrender.com/
github - https://github.com/sayak-op/rayzorpay-clone-1

help me to find my issu.

can u guys find the issue.

Comment: *How* is tailwind CSS not working? Do you get any errors?